# prove x^((pq−p−q+3)/2) ≡ x mod pq.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-set-theory

when $p $ and $q $ are distinct odd primes prove that $x^{\frac{pq−p−q+3}{2}}\equiv x \mod pq
$
i was thinking a start could be to try and factorise the $ pq-p-p+3 $ bit to have $x^{(1/2(1-p)(1-q))}$ multiplied by $x $ like in theorem 12.2 here https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~daw/teaching/cs70-f03/Notes/lecture12b.pdf 
but im not sure where to go from there

Comment: Hiint: Show that $(p-1)(q-1)/2$ is divisible by both $p-1$ and $q-1$. Use the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$\varphi(pq)=(p-1)(q-1)$$

and also

$$\frac12(p-1)(q-1)=\frac{p-1}2(q-1)=(p-1)\frac{q-1}2$$